# Exposing static files in Ruby on Rails 3.1+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to use SoundManager2 to play sounds in my Ruby on Rails application.  One of the things it wants is a directory with swfs. Where do I put it and then how do I configure my soundmanager?  I want to put them in a directory /soundmanager/ and use JS such as the following:

```
<script>
if (soundManager) {
  soundManager.setup({
    url: '/soundmanager/',
    onready: function() {
      var myGameMusic = soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'music1',
        url: 'music1.wav'
      });
      myGameMusic.play();
    },
    ontimeout: function() {
      console.log("Error in soundManager.setUp")
      // Hrmm, SM2 could not start. Missing SWF? Flash blocked? Show an error, etc.?
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Where do I put the swfs (/soundmanager/) and how do I configure it to be public?

A related question is: suppose I have some PDFs that I want to make downlaodable.  Where do I put those so that they're downloadable?

I'm confused because there is a /public directory but apparently it doesn't work in rails 3.1 anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put them in `app/assets/`

The key is that they are served from there *in development mode*.

In *production mode*, the assets are minified and placed in `public/`

This is called 'asset compilation' and was introduced in Rails 3.1 and has caused a lot of confusion as you have seen.

Comment: Asset compilation seems good. So suppose I have a file at app/assets/soundmanager/soundmanager2.swf. What URL gives you the file? Visiting mydomain.com/soundmanager/soundmanager2.swf gives me a "No route" error.

Comment: @Jeff you'll probably want to use the `asset_path` helper in your views. In production, your asset filenames will be suffixed with a hash. And BTW the path is always `mydomain.com/assets/someasset-somehash.extension`

Answer (score 1):

The web server should be serving static resources alongside Rails (not *through* Rails).

I had to do this to get a phpMyAdmin installation working with a Rails app on Apache/Passenger.

```
# Apache vhosts.conf
<Location ~ "/static_content"> 
  PassengerEnabled off 
</Location>
```

This serves content in `/static_content` directly from Apache, bypassing Rails completely. Ideally, this is the optimal solution to static content in any case.